Questions about theroem on properties of ideal quotient/colon ideal
Background
Definition. Let $I,J \unlhd R$ be ideals of the commutative ring $R$.  Then
$$(I:J):=\{r\in R\mid rJ\subseteq I\}$$
is called the ideal quotient or the residual quotient of $I$ and $J$.
Theorem:  Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I,J$ be ideals of $R$.  ALso let $S$ be a subset of $R$.
$(a)$ The set $(I:S)=\{r\in R\mid rs\in I \text{ for all } s\in S\}$ is an ideal of $R$ and in particfular,
$(b)$ $(I:J)$ is an ideal of $R$, in fact the largest ideal $K$ of $R$ such that $KJ\subseteq I$.  In particular, $I\subseteq (I:J)$.
Questions
I have a few quick questions about $(a)$ and $(b)$ of Theorem above,
$(1)$  How do $(I:S)$ differs from $(I:J)$ and why the later is a special case of the former.
$(2)$  In $(b)$ where it says "...in fact the largest ideal $K$ of $R$ such that $KJ\subseteq I$".  Does $KJ\subseteq I$ relate to $(I:J)$ in the following sense: every elements of $x\in K$ such that $xJ\subseteq I$?
$(3)$ do the subset relation $I\subseteq (I:J)$ imply $(I:J)\subset I$ also?
$(4)$ The proof of $I\subseteq (I:J)$, where $I, J$ are ideals of the commutative ring $R$ goes as follows:

If $i\in I$ then certainly $ij\in I$ for all $j\in J$ which gives the relation $I\subseteq (I:J)$.

In the proof abobve, when $i\in I$, is it still assumed that $rJ\subseteq I$ for all $r\in R$?  Also, it seems ithat it is implicitly using the subset relation $KJ\subseteq I$?
$(5)$ Lastly in what sense is $(I:J)$ consider as a quotient?  I mean nothing is getting mod out.
Thank you in advance

What's the problem with $(1)$? $(I:S)$, $(I:J)$ are two examples of the same notation. $S$ can be an ideal, or, not. $rs\in I$ for all $s\in S$ iff. $rS\subseteq I$

@FShrike hey how are you?  for (1) I am just not sure why it says "in particular".  I am getting the impression that one is a special case of the other.  Also, what about the issues from (3) and (4)?  thanks

I'm good thanks, hope you are likewise. It says 'in particular' because yes, one is a special case of the other. $(I:S)$ makes sense for any set $S$, and you can specialise that to when $S=J$ is an ideal. For $(3)$, why would this follow? Think - $I\subseteq A$ does not mean $A\subset I$ in general, for general sets $A$. You're basically saying $(I:J)=I$ always happens, which is wrong (I'm not sure what your justification was). For $(4)$, $rJ\subseteq I$ for all $r$ .. doesn't make sense. This happens only if $J\subseteq I$, which isn't given here.

The reason $ij\in I$ is that $I$ is also an ideal; $i\in I$, so anything multiplied by $i$ is in $I$. The 'assumption' is instead that $Ir\subseteq I$, which is true by definition of ideal.
